# AZURE SQL DATA IMPORT

Tags: azure, azure-sql

I want to move data from one azure sql database to new azure sql database.
From the first one I have exported .bacpac file.
I import it to the second one and I get

```
Import operation for <database_name> failed. ErrorCode: N/A ErrorMessage: Failure
```

What is wrong, I have tested different names, different admin users etc.

Comment: Please update your question with the commands you've tried and the error messages they generated.

Comment: @user2320464 I've made it using only import/export buttons on Azure Portal and that's all I know

Comment: Your question needs more detail. As is, it wouldn't surprise me if it was closed for being low quality or not answered at all.

Answer (score 0):

To get some more information on why this is failing can you follow the steps in [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/09/07/how-to-get-more-information-about-failed-import-to-azure-sql-db/) to get some more detail. This should point us in the right direction to help you with a fix.

James

Answer (score 0):

Please review and follow the instructions detailed here: [Import a BACPAC file to a new Azure SQL Database](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-import)

It is suggested that the .bacpac file be uploaded to Azure Storage to be sourced by the Azure SQL Database it is going to be imported.

Any errors or issues you encounter should be detailed here so as to identify and help you resolve them.